# Macro validation and conditional check

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, conditional-formatting

i have below excel where i want to do data validation for ColumnName1 ColumnName2 ColumnName3 & ColumnName4 and as well check the condition  if `ColumnName6 = ColumnName7 && ColumnName5 = OK` then `ColumnName8 is NOC else CON` using Macros

For condition check i am using below formula unable to get how to use third condition

```
if(ColumnName6 = ColumnName7 ,NOC,CON)
```

For Validation check i am written below macros but its no working as expected

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, msg As String
    If Intersect(Target, ColumnName1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Intersect(Target, ColumnName1)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If Not r.Value Like "########-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]" Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Entry", vbCritical, r.Value
                r.ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Len(msg) Then MsgBox msg, , "Invalid entry"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In `For Each r In Intersect(Target, ColumnName1)` you iterate over all cells in an intersection range. Maybe it is more clear to iterate over rows in this intersection range and check the integrity for the whole row?

Comment: Is there any other way I can write this code

Comment: Try the pattern `"########-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*"` (8 digits, dash, 3 letters, **any amount of any symbols**).